# Getting route distance given two geo coordinates

Tags: windows-phone-7, bing-maps

I am creating a windows phone application which uses map control in it. I want to calculate the driving distance between two geo coordinates in windows phone? can any help on this please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to work through this example in MSDN Magazine http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh148148.aspx

It explains how to do the routing and get the distance property in the results.